# Visualise data loaded in memory from databases/tables for doc purposes

Tags: java, mysql, uml, diagram, use-case

I have a set of classes that do load data from some tables from multiple databases and keep the data in memory in specific data structures (Maps etc).
What I want to do is create some visual/documentation of how each structure is loaded by which db/table.
Is there something other than e.g. google doc or Word doc to use for this? Would it be some form of UML diagram or is it some other kind of diagram I should be looking into?

E.g.
`HashMap<Integer, Person>` is loaded from `emp.Employees` and `personal.People` etc

Answer (score 1):

A very typical way to document this it to use UML stereotypes to identify classes that represent database objects (tables, views, ...),  and show dependency between the "in-memory" classes and the database objects.

Example:

```
+------------+                 +--------------+
|   Person   |                 |   <<table>>  |
+------------+    <<load>>     |   Employees  |
| ...        | - - - - - - - > +--------------+
+------------+ \               | ...          |
| ...        |                 +--------------+
+------------+   \
                       +------------+
                   \-> |  <<table>> |
                       |   People   |
                       +------------+
                       | ...        |
                       +------------+
```

You could then show that `Person` is in a container.  Typically in UML you could show this either with a simple association with a container class or, in the case of the hashmap, with a [qualifier](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.2/model_domains/qualifiers.html).

You may also want to use the full name of your tables,  or use package notation to group tables in the same schema.

Additional example:  [visual mapping of classes and tables using `<<table>>`](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/foreignKeyMapping.html); [use-dependencies to show load/saving relationships](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: Is there a name for this UML diagram. If I recall correctly UML has distinct set of diagrams to represent notions. Additionally is it generally useful to show which columns are used for the `<<load>>` and if so how should they be displayed?

Comment: @Jim this is a class diagram (sorry for the ascii art,  but today, upload of pictures seems not to work).  `<<table>>`and `<<load>>`are called stereotypes (the definitions of such "custom" stereotypes is made in a "profile").   In theory you could have dependencies mapped at attribute level (although not every tool support it).  The problem, is that at this detailed level, a diagram can become very difficult to read.  The usual practice is therefore to keep the dependency at the table level, and describe in a a text the more detailed mappings (often there may be additional conversion rules)

Comment: what would be a good uml tool to use for this?

Comment: Also could you show how would I represent e.g a `Map<Integer, Person> people` which is a Person's member variable and loaded by processing of the two tables (`Employess` and `People`)?

Comment: @Jim we do not provide resources/tools here. But there are only a few on the market, so tou could try the one or the other.

Comment: @Jim the map would be represented by a class that has a one to n relationship to Person. You could add an open arrow head on the side of the person since an efficient navigation is guaranteed. If you want to insist on the key, you would show it with a qualifier. See link provided in the answer for examples and tricky details about using a qualifier.